# Selecting and displaying date from two tables using JOIN and an associative ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of employees in one MySQL table, and a list of assignments in another.

The employees list contains these 4 fields:

```
+––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
| userid | emp_name | emp_email    | emp_role |
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
|   4    |   Jane   | emp@emp.com  |   admin  |
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
|   5    |   John   | emp2@emp.com |   guest  |
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
```

and in the `assignments` table, I have a list of jobs

```
+–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
| userid | job_name |   job_numb   |    due_date   |
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
|   4    |   Job1   | 012221200000 |   01/21/2017  |
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
|   5    |   Job2   | 012221200001 |   01/24/2017  |
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
```

What I would like is to have all the information from both tables be accessible for data. What I initially wrote is:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
$sql = "SELECT * FROM assignments JOIN employees";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    ?>
```

Then in a loop:

```
<table>

<?php
    foreach ($results as $result){
        $userid = $result['userid'];
        $emp_name = $result['emp_name'];
        $emp_email = $result['emp_email'];
        $emp_role = $result['emp_role'];
        $job_name = $result['job_name'];
        $job_numb = $result['job_numb'];
        $due_date = $result['due_date'];

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $emp_name;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $emp_email;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $emp_role;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $job_name;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $job_numb;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $due_date;?></td>
?>
<?php
    }
?>
</table>
```

Of course, this just outputs everything. I am having trouble understanding how to relate the data from table 1 to table 2 so what I get is the email and name of the employee associated with that job. Is there a way to have a conditional in the `foreach` statement?

Comment: What is in jobs_canjobs?

Comment: Oh sorry! Supposed to be assignments for purposes of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting the JOIN condition (a.userid = e.userid) as far as I can see. Without this condition in the WHERE clause of your SQL statement, you will get a [cross product](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/mysql-cross-join.php) of all tuples from both tables.

Try the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM assignments a JOIN employees e WHERE a.userid = e.userid;
```

Note that for the sake of conciseness, I have introduced aliases for the two tables.

Comment: This was good for making the tables join :) Now I have to figure out another step. Thank you sir!

Comment: I'm glad I helped.

Comment: Both this solution and @Rajdeep Paul 's answers seemed to work - I simply marked this one because it was first and because the rep levels.

Comment: Thanks @scoopzilla ;)

Answer (score 1):

A simple `JOIN` without any `ON` condition is like doing the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of two tables. You need to use `ON` as a join condition in your query. So your query should be like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM assignments JOIN employees ON employees.userid = assignments.userid";
```

Comment: I don't know why this statement didn't work yet the other did.

Comment: @scoopzilla It's working as expected. See the working fiddle here, [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47fc61/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47fc61/1)

Comment: Let me try again :)

Comment: No yeah, worked very well! Can you tell me why the cartesian product is bad though?

Comment: @scoopzilla Cartesian product is not *bad*, sometimes it's required in some applications. Since your question says, *how to relate the data from table 1 to table 2 so what I get is the email and name of the employee associated with that job*, you need to use `ON` as join condition in your query.